# How to convert any video to mp4 with php, ffmpeg and CentOS

Tags: centos, php, video, ffmpeg

I have been converting videos for about a year working in localhost on a Mac. The path is, '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg' and it has always worked fine. Recently, I installed ffmpeg on my server, with a CentOS 8 operating system, and the php script I have recently used is not working. My question is, 'Where is the path for ffmpeg in CentOS 8?'

Comment: what does `which ffmpeg` say?

Comment: It says 'bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg'

Answer (score 2):

On the Mac I will assume you installed ffmpeg with `brew` which does a local build, hence why it ends up under `/usr/local`

The build for centos probably comes as a pre-built RPM installed with `dnf` or `yum` so under normal circumstances will be installed into `/usr/bin`.

The `which` command will will search the PATH variable to find the command passed as an argument. e.g.:

```
$ which ffmpeg
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong in the command line in the php file: exec($ffmpeg . ' -i "' . $uploaded_file . '" -c:v libx264 "./testuploads/converted/' . $video_mp4 . '" -y 1>convert.txt 2>&1', $output, $convert_status['mp4']);

Comment: @margie update the question and show the complete script. however web development is off topic on serverfault.com